# Render Scripts-Section after scripts were loaded in ASP.NET Core PartialView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In an ASP.NET Core app, I've a dashboard with widgets. Every widget has its own PartialViews, so the full page is generated in the following way:

-Layout.cshtml

--Dashboard.cshtml

--- Widget1.cshtml

--- Widget2.cshtml

Following best practices according to fast page load times, JavaScript is loaded before the closing `</body>` tag in Layout.cshtml. After that, there is a section for custom JS, which I commonly use to initiate objects on page load. So this section looks like this:

```
<script asp-append-version="true" type="text/javascript" src="~/clientscript/page.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Js", required: false)
```

In my Views, which are using the Layout.cshtml as layout (in this example, its Dashboard.cshtml), I can define a section like

```
@section Js {
    // Js Code here
}
```

which is rendered after the script tag containing all script files. So I can be sure, that all dependencies like jQuery or custom classes are avaliable here.

*But* I also need to do this in widgets like Widget1.cshtml for example. The problem is: I load the PartialView Widget1.cshtml in Dashboard.cshtml. In the [documentation is written](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial), that this is not possible:

> If you declare a Razor section in a partial view, it will not be visible to its parent(s); it will be limited to the partial view.

But that's exactly what I need. Is there a way to work around this limitation? Shortly, the goal is to inject JavaScript from a PartialView to the LayoutView, with an regular View between them.

The only way I know is the usage of setInterval() with a low interval like 50ms, and check there if jQuery or some of my custom class is defined in a loop until they are. Its a JS solution yes. But it makes it possible to include the script-block directly in the PartialView without making usage of sections. It fits well when you depend on a single variable like jQuery.

But I need to wait for custom classes to get loaded. They're included after jQuery. So writing a generic function like `waitForTypeLoaded(type, callback)` is not possible. It would cause me to write always the raw setInterval() code, which seems not a smart solution for me.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you need, but a partial view still has access to the assets rendered by the parent (like css, js,  etc).  Are you saying you wan to run a script within `widget1.cshtml`, but the support scripts haven't been rendered yet?  if that is the case, youll need to write a js event to let you know when its loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Something I did to get my scripts to run after Jquery was done loading was in my Partial Views and View Components I used the "DOMContentLoaded" event to load all my jQuery js script after the page was done loading. That way I could defer the Load of jQuery and Still Have jQuery code on my pages.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
        function() {
            $('body')....

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved as mentioned in my answer to this post: 
[How to render scripts, generated in TagHelper process method, to the bottom of the page rather than next to the tag element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313529/how-to-render-scripts-generated-in-taghelper-process-method-to-the-bottom-of-t/31968318#31968318)

To sum up, you can create a pair of tag helpers, one that can be located in a partial view and just stores its content in a temporary dictionary, and the other that renders the content at the appropriate position (e.g. in the layout page). I use it extensively to render small dynamically created scripts as the final scripts of the body.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, I would make one step back and look at architecture once again if you have such dilemmas.

Why not add to required scripts which will be used on a couple of views/partial views to the main layout? In ASP.NET MVC you can use bundling mechanism (or you can write our own) - minify and bundle them with other required. It won't be heavy...

Your approach looks like unnecessary complicated.

Comment: .ASP.NET MVC Core bundling works differently and would not work nicely for this scenario.