# Inject JavaScript from a Tag Helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

While in ASP.NET Core 2.0, I am trying to create a tag helper that relies on some custom JavaScript -- so, the idea is that the tag helper will inject the onchange event and then add code to do a postback to the server. Ideally, I don't want to have a separate JavaScript file but rather have the tag helper inject the javascript into the page.

This is similar in functionality to what was available in earlier versions of ASP.NET via a call to `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

Is that possible to inject JavaScript into the page using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: please add a sample of what you have tried - it's usually easier to advise on that way.

Comment: Sounds like this answer may be your solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31839554/231716